# PHP - Can I use mb_detect_encoding () + iconv() to convert strings to UTF-8?

Tags: php, unicode

All,

I am building a small web app that will accept user-generated content.  This content will be **uploaded via a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` form & a browse button**.

As I understand `mb_detect_encoding()`, it cannot distinguish between character sets that are subsets of each others if the string doesn't include characters that are not in the overlap.  That makes sense.

My question is: does this matter?  If I use `mb_detect_encoding()` to get PHP's best guess, and then use this best guess to encode into UTF-8 using `iconv()`, am I going to run into trouble, and if so why?

In other words, if `mb_detect_encoding()` come up with the wrong encoding on a small string that is entirely inside the overlap of 2 charsets, will I get a different result when I then do `iconv()` than I would if I had used the proper input encoding in the function?

EDIT:  I rewrote the question to specifically address text files uploaded via browse buttons.

Comment: Is it really necessary to detect the encoding in the first place if all the forms are properly encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: mb_detect_encoding() is used for a best guess when you don't know the charset, not when you do know it

Comment: @Pekka - not sure it is for text entered into a form, but what about texts that are uploaded by the user via a browse button & a `enctype="multipart/form-data"` form?

Comment: Also, are there not cases when the user (or their browser) could circumvent the restriction I put in the HTML?

Comment: @JDelage re the document: then you are screwed :) the only good way to deal with that is to show the user a preview of the uploaded document, and a select box with various encodings, letting them select the right encoding. OpenOffice does it that way, for example, when importing CSVs. Re the browser: that shouldn't happen in a modern browser (I think; no idea whether exceptions exist)

Comment: @Pekka - I still don't understand what happens when I apply those two functions and PHP makes the wrong guess.  What happens then with the converted `utf-8` string?

Comment: @JDelage it will contain invalid characters and they will show up as ���. (Or the invalid characters will be dropped if you add `//IGNORE` to the third argument of `iconv()`)